# java reader vs. stream

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, filereader

I was reading about Java I/O and found some interesting areas like streams, readers etc.

```
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream("input-file.txt");
 int data = input.read();
 while(data != -1){
   data = input.read();
 }
```

I can do the same thing by using Readers as follows:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("input-file.txt");
 int data = reader.read();
 while(data != -1){
     char dataChar = (char) data;
     data = reader.read();
 }
```

As I know, Streams are used to retrieve input from continuously flowing data.

Now I am confused with the difference between Streams & readers; and if we wraps the stream with a buffered reader - how it break lines, since stream is a continuously flowing thing.

I found some reference sites like [this site.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/index.html) But I can't understand the difference.

Please can someone please help me to understand?

Comment: Start with the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis , But I need a comparison. and i need to understand the procedure how break lines in BufferedReaders. Can you help me please?

Comment: An InputStream isn't a Stream... that's a totally different thing.

Comment: Look at the source - http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileReader.java/?v=source - A FileReader is just an InputStreamReader and a FileInputStream.

Comment: The comparison you need is right there in the Javadoc: [This abstract class is the superclass of all classes representing an input stream of bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [Abstract class for reading character streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html). There isn't any more to it than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readers are to read text data with particular character encoding (UTF-8, ISO etc..)

while on the other hand, streams are binary data.

They work same but there parent classes are different.

in a nutshell, if you have to read binary data and save it somewhere, use stream.

If you have to read text in a particular encoding and then play with it, then use readers.

Hope this answers.

Comment: So basically readers what readers doing is read from stream and encode to characters. am i right. and if we wraps the stream with a buffered reader, how it break lines since stream is a continuously flowing thing ?

Comment: line breaks are read by newline character \n . this functionality is inside readLine(). It reads characters until it finds \n.. Yes you are right in first part.

Comment: so, if i'm using bufferedReader , but doesn't have line breaks.

Comment: whole text means, whole buffered string until that time ?